# ansible 2.3.0 - No authentication methods available

Tags: ansible

I have installed ansible on ubuntu server using:

```
 pip install git+git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git@devel
```

So my curent version is:

```
ansible 2.3.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

In configuration file I have:

```
# uncomment this to disable SSH key host checking
host_key_checking = False
```

And when I run ansible I get:

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:

PLAYBOOK: test1.yml ************************************************************
1 plays in test1.yml

PLAY [testowy playbook] ********************************************************

TASK [show version] ************************************************************
task path: /home/mszczesniak/test1.yml:8
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/core/network/ios/ios_command.py
<10.27.200.80> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.27.200.80> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846 `" ) && sleep 0'
<10.27.200.80> PUT /tmp/tmpNfII7q TO /home/mszczesniak/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846/ios_command.py
<10.27.200.80> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/mszczesniak/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846/ /home/mszczesniak/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846/ios_command.py && sleep 0'
<10.27.200.80> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/mszczesniak/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846/ios_command.py; rm -rf "/home/mszczesniak/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1477054111.24-214066525349846/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_module_ios_command.py", line 237, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_module_ios_command.py", line 200, in main
    runner.add_command(**cmd)
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/netcli.py", line 147, in add_command
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network.py", line 116, in cli
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network.py", line 147, in connect
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/ios.py", line 180, in connect
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/shell.py", line 230, in connect
  File "/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/shell.py", line 100, in open
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 367, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 585, in _auth
    raise SSHException('No authentication methods available')
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No authentication methods available

fatal: [10.27.200.80]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "ios_command"
    },
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_module_ios_command.py\", line 237, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_module_ios_command.py\", line 200, in main\n    runner.add_command(**cmd)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/netcli.py\", line 147, in add_command\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network.py\", line 116, in cli\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network.py\", line 147, in connect\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/ios.py\", line 180, in connect\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/shell.py\", line 230, in connect\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_zKWzh_/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/shell.py\", line 100, in open\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py\", line 367, in connect\n    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py\", line 585, in _auth\n    raise SSHException('No authentication methods available')\nparamiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No authentication methods available\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/mszczesniak/test1.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.27.200.80               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

What is wrong? It looks like option in a config file is not taken or maby there is problem in dev 2.3.0 version?

Answer (score 2):

This exception is raised when you do not provide any means for authentication. The Paramiko SSH Client doesn't know what method to use and hence raises `SSHException('No authentication methods available')`.

You should provide either a password or a private key (or both), for the SSHClient to work. Else, it's just clueless.

A little extra:
If you [look at the code](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/a6b7648d93eb36d8e52b5761604b187d02bc1b5a/paramiko/client.py#L622), you can see that this exception is raised when none of the possible auth methods have been tried.

Answer (score 0):

if we are adding the below parameters

```
ansible_user=rakesh
ansible_password=xxxxx
```

it is giving **"unable to set terminal parameters"** error

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29844782)